# Arabic keywords in URL in two levels

Tags: seo, url, internationalization, localization, rtl

I know that localized Arabic keywords in URL are really good for SEO, but my question is what if I want to localize the category also, let us say that my website structure is like `blog/category/post`, if URL is localized in Arabic then it will look like this `blog/منشور/تصنيف` which is good for the looking eye but since the URL gets encoded and decoded it's original form is like this `blog/post/category( in Arabic )`.

In other words in order to generate a link in Arabic that looks like this `blog/category/post` the URL should be structured like this `blog/post/category`. Is this good or bad for SEO? To the naked eye and on search results the URL should look naturally like this `blog/تصنيف(category)/منشور(post)` but in reality it is structured in this way `blog/منشور(post)/تصنيف(category)`?

Comment: Your breaking rule 1. User experience. The term SEF URL is outdated, since Google and Bing can rank pages with little or no keywords in the URL path since it can obtain those signals from other page elements. Your URLS should be short and provide pre-click information what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

I have pages indexed with Google with arabic and foreign characters in the URL. I think this is good for driving foreign traffic to my site. One link looks like this: example.com/अजमेर

I'm also using a lot of encoding and decoding to convert the foreign characters to US-EN.

One thing that you can do is create blog/منشور/تصنيف and call the page you want with file_get_contents('blog/post/category'); This will keep the arabic characters in the URL while being able to call the English character version if that makes it easier for you to work with. You may also want to add the rel=canonical tag to blog/post/category pointing to blog/منشور/تصنيف so that Google knows which page you prefer to have indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your URLs as a Unicode with this tool **[URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)**. Your example URL will look like the following: `blog/%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%81/%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%B1` 
To check, open the browser (I used Chrome) and install this line in the browser's address bar. Result:

[image]

I hope that this will happen to you.